# Can we use jQuery UI price range slider value with input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using `Jquery UI price range slider` this is working perfectly but I want price value with input text and that will be editable.

Anybody can do it?

If anybody has any other plugin or custom code & suggestion then please share.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could just add a Textbox and have that value influence the slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go. Bind `onchange` event to inputs, remove `readonly` and that's it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [75, 300],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#amount_min").val(ui.values[0]);
          $("#amount_max").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
      });
      $("#amount_min").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
      $("#amount_max").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
      $("#amount_min").change(function() {
        $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0, $(this).val());
      });
      $("#amount_max").change(function() {
        $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1, $(this).val());
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
    $<input type="text" id="amount_min" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    $<input type="text" id="amount_max" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="slider-range"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/n4h6624h/

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
      
    $('#amount').focusout(function(){
     var sliderVal = $(this).val();
      var splitSliderVal = sliderVal.replace(/\$/g, '').split('-');
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
       values: [ parseInt(splitSliderVal[0]), parseInt(splitSliderVal[1]) ]
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```